# Put a multi-page PDF into a doc file

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, libreoffice, headers

I need to insert a 400 page PDF with a header for a report.

Word is what I have the header in. Inserting PDF into word results in one page showing up (brilliant there, engineers).

Converting PDF to image results in only one page showing up.

Libre office converting the PDF to odg doesn't help: it inserts only the first page again, word is unable to handle ODG.

Complaining to my bosses this is idiotic to require a header on it doesn't help either.

PS: Paying for dodgy third party converters seems like a good way to waste time and money.

Comment: @interkinetic A) Must the final report be in a Word file? If not, try http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/add-headers-footers-pdfs.html B) Also relevant: Is the source PDF a Real /True / Normal PDF, searchable by default, where content (text and images) can be copy/pasted into other file formats? If not, if it is merely a Scanned or Searchable PDF, that limits your options greatly. C) http://pdfsam.org/download-pdfsam-basic is free, open source, and non-dodgy if you have a Scanned/Searchable PDF & need to burst the file into 400 one page PDFs D) Bosses are a great way to waste time and money.

Comment: Have you tried simply using one of the many online converter tools like https://pdf2doc.com/ ?

Comment: @BoffinBrain, yes, they generally demand payment for anything more than a few pages

Comment: @K7AAY Unfortunately the handwriting on the pages is important, not text recognition. It could be converted to an image, that's a valid file conversion, but still has the only one page posting issue in word and libre office. 

PDFsam appears to have the same "freemium for anything useful" model. If I wanted to pay, I'd get adobe PDF pro.

Comment: I haven't a clue personally, but this is an interesting question. I wonder if getting more creative on the formats allowed would make this doable. Can headers be injected in the printing process? Or would saving each page as an image, perhaps some sort of "print to JPG" and then using those to build the document?

Comment: One trick I can think of is taking the original PDF and 'printing' a range of pages to a number of new PDFs that are each under the limits that those online tools impose. With 400 pages, it may take a while, though!

Comment: @interkin3tic pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit is another tool which, for free, will 'burst' each page out of a PDF into its own file so the header can be added. Then. if you want the 400 pages reassembled into one PDF, it will do that for you as well, or not.

Answer (score 0):

Would it meet your needs to use "Edit PDF" > "Header & Footer" > "Add" and insert the header information into the pdf file?

(based on Adobe Acrobat Pro DC)